# Configuring paths for Zend Framework to load files correctly

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, path, public

I am trying to load a developed Zend Project in my machine, but when I try accessing it in browser ("localhost:8888/projectroot/public"), image files, .js and .css scripts which are in public folder are not found.

Files are being searched in the root folder (e.g.: http:// [localhost]:8888/image.png), instead of inside the "public" folder.

What I am missing? Do I miss any path configuration in php.ini, Apache, or something like this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to configure a virtual host pointing on public :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /path/to/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /path/to/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

on file localised in : apache/conf/httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

How are you writing the paths for those files in the HTML?

```
<img src="image.png"/>
<img src="/image.png"/>
<img src="../image.png"/>
<img src="public/image.png"/>
```

etc, etc.

Check to see if your writing the correct path, pointing to "public", in the src attribute.